# Rviz problem after installing Hydro

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-hydro, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was unable to open some urdf files in rviz with errors like 'could not find stack/package' 'cannot load model'. To check if they are opening in MoveIt i installed ROS hydro. urdf file is still gave the same error. However, along with that i was unable to open urdf files (that worked fine with groovy initially) in both groovy and hydro. In hydro the error was same 'could not find stack/package' while in groovy it was

```
ERROR: the config file '/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_tutorials/urdf_tutorial/urdf.vcg' is a .vcg file, which is the old rviz config format.
   New config files have a .rviz extension and use YAML formatting.  The format changed
   between Fuerte and Groovy.  There is not (yet) an automated conversion program.
```

Now, i have uninstalled hydro but groovy is giving same errors and my urdf files in rviz are still not opening.
Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99786/rviz-problem-after-installing-hydro/) by [Akshay_Bhardwaj_nsit](https://answers.ros.org/users/8321/akshay_bhardwaj_nsit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the Groovy error has nothing to do with the urdf files themselves.  I'm guessing that you are calling a launch file that is opening rviz with the urdf.vcg file using the -d argument.  This is throwing the error because rviz in groovy doesn't use vcg files anymore.  On my system in `/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_tutorials/urdf_tutorial/` I have a urdf.vcg file, and a display.launch file that explicitly sets the urdf.vcg configuration.  In `/opt/ros/groovy/share/urdf_tutorial` I have a display.launch file that instead uses a urdf.rviz file.  This is the correct launch file, and it should work for you.

Right now, on Groovy, there are two apt-get packages that both wrap up the files I've been talking about.  `ros-groovy-urdf-tutorial` provides the correct display.launch file, and `ros-groovy-robot-model-tutorials` provides the one that you are trying to call.  To call the correct display.launch, check that you have the urdf-tutorial package installed.

Alternatively, you could just copy the launch file and comment or edit the calls to rviz. If you are using your own launch file, then you probably just need to edit it a bit.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1